# StarCluster - How to create new AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm getting started with StarCluster in AWS. I want to use SGE as the queue manager, which appears to be the default.

I'm using RHEL and I cannot find a StarCluster pubic AMI. Hence, it seems like I have to build my own image, right? Is there a StarCluster document somewhere that outlines what should be installed in this image?

Most importantly, do I need to install SGE? Would I just need to install, but not actually go through the whole SGE configuration process?

I started my cluster successfully, but this was the last warning message, "!!! ERROR - SGE is not installed on this AMI, skipping..."

Comment: Here's an Ubuntu AMI: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00ETJXX3O/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-2&qid=1428796960994
more info: http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/0.91/list_public_amis.html

Comment: Thanks @dmourati ... All I'm getting at is that there seems to be a disconnect between installing StarCluster and assuming SGE is installed and configured on the AMIs, There's no RHEL image available in the community.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was build my own RHEL image. I already had a compiled instance of SGE 2.6u15, so I copied this to /opt/sge6-fresh. This was found in StarCluster source code:

```
> starcluster/plugins/sge.py
   ...
   SGE_FRESH = "/opt/sge6-fresh"
```

Once that was done, I generated an new AMI and updated my starcluster config to point to this new AMI ID.

From what I can tell, when the cluster is stood up, starcluster essentially copies /opt/sge6-fresh to /opt/sge6 and proceeds with configuring SGE using the new AWS cluster information.